# Increment and decrement

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make 2 buttons for both increment and decrement of value. So if I increase the value of var k = 4 and I press the decrement button it it decreases the value of 4 to 3

I tried this

```js
var k = 1;

function qtrFunction(k, v) {
  document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML = k;
  k++;
  document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML = v;
  v--;
}
v = k;
console.log(k);
```

```html
<div style="color:white; font-size:70px;">QTR <span id="qtrrr" style="color:green; border-radius:10px; padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;">0</span>
</div>


<button onclick="qtrFunction(k)" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="qtrFunction(v)" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
```

Comment: So what error are you getting? Also, you have declared the function `qtrFunction` to accept two parameters but are passing only one.

Comment: 'Increment by Javascript'? Okay: `var foo = 1; foo += javascript` Let me just quickly edit the title for you, right? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var k = 1;
    function qtrFunction(V) {
        if(V=="I")
        {
          k++;
        }
        else
        {
          k--;
        }
        document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML = k;
        console.log(k); 
    }       

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="color:white; font-size:70px;">QTR  <span id="qtrrr" style="color:green; border-radius:10px; padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;">0</span></div>


<button onclick="qtrFunction('I')" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="qtrFunction('D')" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

- Avoid using `innerHTML` as it triggers a parse of the set value string, this is an expensive operation (though it is better than `document.write`). Consider setting `.textContent` instead.
- You haven't declared the `v` local, so you'll get errors about undefined symbols.
- You don't need two values.

Like so:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    var value = 0; // initialize a global variable

    function updateAndDisplay(increment) {
        if( increment ) value++;
        else            value--;
        document.getElementById('qtrrr').textContent = value;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="updateAndDisplay(true)" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="updateAndDisplay(false)" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
```

Comment: You also don't need two functions. Just a sign

Comment: @mplungjan I have simplified my answer

Comment: `updateAndDisplay(1) ... updateAndDisplay(-1) ... value+=increment;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might help you.

```js
var cnt = 0;
function qtrFunction(val) {
  if(val=='k'){
    cnt = document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML = (cnt+1);         
  }else {
    cnt = document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML = (cnt-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="color:white; font-size:70px;">QTR  <span id="qtrrr" style="color:green; border-radius:10px; padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;">0</span></div>
  
  
<button onclick="qtrFunction('k')" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="qtrFunction('v')" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var k = 1;
    function qtrFunction(condition) {
        document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML= condition?k++:k--;
    } 

<button onclick="qtrFunction(true)" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="qtrFunction(false)" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

Just pass the action ( incr or decr) when you are calling the js function and then get the current value and depending on the button pressed incr or decr the value. After that just set it back.

```js
function qtrFunction(action) {
  var value = document.getElementById("qtrrr").innerHTML;
  if (action == "incr") {
    value++;
  } else {
    value--;
  }
  document.getElementById("qtrrr").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<div style="color:white; font-size:70px;">QTR <span id="qtrrr" style="color:green; border-radius:10px; padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;">0</span>
</div>


<button onclick="qtrFunction('incr')" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="qtrFunction('decr')" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
```

Comment: You really should parseInt that counter and get rid of the k which is no longer used

Answer (score 0):

```
This Code May be Helpful for you

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var value = 0; // initialize a global variable

        function incrementAndDisplay() {
        value++;
       alert(value);
        document.getElementById('qtrrr').textContent = value;

        }
       function decrementAndDisplay() {
        value--;
       alert(value);
        document.getElementById('qtrrr').textContent = value;

        }

        console.log(value);


   </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="incrementAndDisplay()" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="decrementAndDisplay()" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful:

```js
var sampleVar = 0;

document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML = sampleVar;

function stepping(step) {
  sampleVar += step;
  document.getElementById('qtrrr').innerHTML = sampleVar;
}
```

```html
<div style="color:white; font-size:70px;">
  QTR <span id="qtrrr" style="color:green; border-radius:10px; padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;"></span>
</div>

<button onclick="stepping(1)" style="padding:15px">Increase Quart</button>
<button onclick="stepping(-1)" style="padding:15px">Decrease Quart</button>
```