# JavaScript newbie learning (increments)

Tags: javascript

starting to learn JavaScript, and I am currently learning incrementations and decrement, is it possible to increment on your desired value?
example: increment = 10

```
let earnedUsd = 10;
 earnedUsd ++;

console.log(earnedUsd ++ = 10);
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) + [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `val += 10` is the same as `val = val + 10` but not really the same as `val++` ten times.

Comment: use += or -= operator.
When you want to use ++, you have to use with loop.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment and decrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474926/increment-and-decrement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. Here are 3 examples to show the solutions. I recommend to use the 1st and 2nd way, 3rd way is not optimal.

```js
//1st way
var a = 5;
a++

//2nd way
var b = 5;
b += 1;

//3rd way
var c = 5;
c = c + 1;

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
```

Comment: 1st way does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

```
let earnedUsd = 10;



console.log(earnedUsd++) // earnedUsd = earnedUsd + 1
console.log(earnedUsd += 10) // earnedUsd = earnedUsd + 10
```

[MDN Increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

[MDN +=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

#### earnedUsd++ increments the value by 1

It returns the new value, which you could (for example) put into another variable or output with console.log. In your case, you are simply incrementing `earnedUsd` and not doing anything with the result. That is fine.

#### You have mis-spelled the second usage: you probably meant earnedUsd += 10

On its own, the following statement will simply increase the stored value of `earnedUsd` by 10.

```
earnedUsd += 10
```

It returns the new value, so you can `console.log` it if you want.

```
console.log(earnedUsd += 10)
```

This will display the new value. This pattern of writing code was common in `C`, but we try to discourage it in Javascript because it can be easy to miss, when skim-reading the code, that you are actually changing the stored value of `earnedUsd`.

`earnedUsd ++= 10` is a syntax error. To add 1, just use `++`. To add 10, just use `+=10`.